# For Loop to add SQL to combobox

Tags: sql, combobox

Hi All I am trying to add items to multiple combo boxes contained in a groupbox, the are also two sets of comboboxes, so I need to differentiate between the 2 sets. I thought of doing it by name.

Please see my code I get an error on ctr.item.add (item is not a member off control)

```
For Each ctr As Control In grpProdDetail.Controls
            If TypeOf ctr Is ComboBox Then
                If ctr.Name Like "drpProdCode" Then
                    SQL.ExQuery("Select EmpNo from dbo.EmpDetail")
                    If SQL.RcCount > 0 Then
                        For Each r As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
                            ctr.item.add(r("EmpNo"))
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ctr.items.add(r("EmpNo"))
```